# How can I schedule my android chat app messages until internet is available

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am currently working on an android chat app with targeted api 30.

The thing is that if the user send a message to any other user than if the network is available than the message is delivered at the instant to the receiver, but if at that moment internet is not available to that app then that message is stored just like Whatsapp Undelivered messages, so that whenever internets is back again then that messages could be retried to send.

I already investigated about it on Google and stackoverflow and found about Workmanager, but I want to schedule immediate tasks so that along with gurantee of work completition, time constraint is also followed.

Comment: You are on the right way, you can indeed use WorkManager and set a `NetworkType.Connected` constraint. So what is your actual question, what does not work?

Comment: @Michiel actually as much as I know with Workmanager the task execution is guranteed, but the thing is the task should be executed as soon as Internet is available but, with WorkManager the immediate execution of task is not guranteed. I just want to make it just like Whatsapp delivers unsent messages when internet is available and with immediate effect.